# Passing arguments in an onPress in ListItem (rendering as undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created a function that takes two arguments. However, when I try pass these in a ListItem as follows, they are being passed as undefined.

My ListItem code where the onPress is called:

```
{this.state.challenges.map((t, i) => (
    < ListItem
        key={i}
        title={i}
        onPress={() => this.handleRequest(t.num_questions, t.id)}
    />
))}
```

My handleRequest code:

```
handleRequest(num_questions, challenge) {

        const payload = {
            num_questions: num_questions,
            challenge: challenge
        }

        console.log(payload);
    }
```

Any ideas why they are not passing?

Comment: what the `this.state.challenges` data looks like?

Comment: Its just an objet array of {id, num_questions}

Comment: `onPress={(t) => this.handleRequest(t.num_questions, t.id)}`